# Div hides when viewing vertically on iPad

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a RWD site with a fixed side navigation that fits to the top of the page when viewed on anything smaller than an iPad. The problem I am running into is when I switch the view to vertical on an iPad the navigation menu on the top of the page disappears. This only happens on the iPad as far as I can tell.

*(keep in mind this is still under development so if you see any bugs please let me know!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in your *style.css* file set display to **none** when max-width is 768px, which is iPad's width on horizontal mode.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

  [...]

  .midnav {
    display: none;
  }
```

By the way, if you connect your iPad to the computer, then **you can use the element inspector for your iPad** if you open Safari and select on the Develop menu your connected iPad. This is very cool and very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, this pinpointed the problem for me :)

Answer (score 1):

At various points in your style sheet, you have your menu sections set to `display: none;`. You are then relying on @media rules to display them again, but they are falling through a few cracks (you are playing Russian roulette with them!).

You can test what's happening in your desktop browser. Slowly resize Chrome, and when you get to about the width and height of an iPad, you see all menus disappear. I recommend you use tests like this while setting up your @media rules.

Comment: With the way the age was designed, as cluttered as the code is, this really was the only way I understood how to do it. I do appreciate your help, thank you!